# Instance subclassing, why are new instances generated?

Tags: python

I'm doing a test, when I subclass an instance of a class, will generate a new instance, and have methods of this class, excuse me, what is the principle?

**This is the test code:**

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, x=None, y=None, z=None):
        print 'base ...'

    def base_func(self):
        print 'base func ...'

t = Base()

class TestA(t):
    pass

print type(t),type(TestA)
t.base_func()
TestA.base_func()
```

**Results of enforcement:**

```
base ...
base ...
<type 'instance'> <type 'instance'>
base func ...
base func ...
```

**A wrong example:**

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, x=None, y=None):
        print 'base ...'

    def base_func(self):
        print 'base func ...'

t = Base()

class TestA(t):
    pass

print type(t),type(TestA)
t.base_func()
TestA.base_func()
```

**Execution will get some errors:**

```
base ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ztest.py", line 11, in <module>
    class TestA(t):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    __init__() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to create a subclass of `t` (which is not a class)? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: 'class Base(object)' , the same result

Comment: just seeing similar code elsewhere, I want to understand the principle.

Comment: Most likely, either that code subclassed actual classes and you just misunderstood, or the code you saw was broken. Listing a non-class object as a base class is almost never correct, and the very few possible legitimate use cases are almost always better handled by writing a metaclass.

Comment: user2357112, thank you for answering this comprehensively, I will go and see the implementation of the metaclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclassing arbitrary objects is not a thing that makes sense. The results you're seeing are not any sort of designed or intended behavior.

When Python constructs a new class, it needs to figure out what *metaclass* to use. The metaclass is the class's class. Since `t` isn't a class at all, the metaclass-finding logic ends up trying to treat `Base` as a metaclass to create `TestA`, since `Base` is the class of the single object `t` you listed as the base "class" of `TestA`.

To create a class, the metaclass is called with three arguments:

- the class *name*,
- a tuple of the *base classes*, and
- the namespace (usually a dict, and always a dict in Python 2) in which the class body was executed

Your first `Base` accepts calls like `Base('TestA', (Base,), {...})`, so the "class" creation succeeds and results in an instance of `Base`. Your second `Base` does not accept such calls, resulting in the `TypeError` you see.